# python script for manipulating excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to write a python script to manipulate the excel spreadsheet.

Suppose if,Ihave the sample data:

```
Gene        chrom    strand  TSS        TES         Name

NM_145215   chr5     +       135485168  135488045   Abhd11

NM_1190437  chr5     +       135485021  135488045   Abhd11

NM_1205181  chr14    +       54873803   54888844    Abhd4

NM_134076   chr14    +       54878906   54888844    Abhd4

NM_9594     chr2     +       31615464   31659747    Abl1

NM_1112703  chr2     +       31544075   31659747    Abl1

NM_207624   chr11    +       105829258  105851278   Abl1

NM_9598     chr11    +       105836521  105851278   Ace2

NM_1130513  chrX     +       160577273  160626350   Ace2

NM_27286    chrX     +       160578411  160626350   Ace2
```

For those similar names(column 6), I want to retrieve the whole row with least TSS.
Example, for first 2 rows-Abhd11 name, I want to save the 2nd row in my result since the TSS 135485021 < 135485168. So on for all the sets with same NAMES.

Any ideas and comments are appreciated.

Comment: Is this really an excel file or a delineated text file?  If excel is it XLS or XLSX?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Regardless of the input format, I would read the file, create a dictionary with the Name as the key, and just keep the row with the minimum values in it.  You also have not specified what you want the output to look like . . .

Comment: There are three ways to do this: 1. Require the Excel file to be saved as .csv instead of .xls(x), then you can use the built-in csv module in Python. 2. Require Excel to be present on the machine, then use PyCOM (Windows)/appscript (Mac) to make it do the work for you. 3. Require nothing, and write your own Python code to parse .xls(x) files (possibly not parsing the entire format, or using and wrapping code from LibreOffice or other projects), which is going to be a ton of work. So, will either 1 or 2 work for you?

Answer (score 4):

**Input**

If possible I would save the excel file as a csv file and then load into python using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

Alternatively you could use the [`xlrd` module for reading excel files](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html) - though I haven't used this and don't know much about it.

[`openpyxl`](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/) is an additional option for parsing the excel file (cheers Just another dunce).

**Manipulation**

ernie's idea seems workable, and I would implement it as follows. 
Assuming that `linesreadfromfile` is a list of lists as read using `csv.reader` i.e. each list element is a list of values that corresponds to the delimited entries of that row in the file,

```
finaldict = {}
for row in linesreadfromfile:
    if finaldict.has_key(row[5]):
        if finaldict[row[5]][3] > row[3]:
            finaldict[row[5]] = row
    else:
        finaldict[row[5]] = row
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the best answer, unless for some reason the user can't require the files to be in .csv format (or needs information that can't be preserved in that format).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the xlrd module.  I've used it to read through Excel files and it's pretty easy to work with.  Highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with mutzmatron and would recommend the `xlrd` module.  Here's a simple example:

```
import xlrd

# Create your file handle
file_handle = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)

# Use the first page in the spreadsheet (0-based indexes)
sheet = file_handle.sheet_by_index(0)

# Create dictionary for storing values
abc = {}

# Loop through every row
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
  line = sheet.row_values(i)

  # Get your 'Name' and 'TSS' columns
  name = line[5]
  tss = line[3]

  # Add this 'Name' to your dictionary if it's new, or keep the max value
  if name not in abc.keys():
    abc[name] = tss
  else:
    abc[name] = max(abc[name],tss)
```

Obviously changing what you'd need to save (full row, certain values, etc.) based on your spec.

--- EDIT ---

```
  # If this 'Name' is new, save this line
  if name not in abc.keys():
    abc[name] = {'tss': tss, 'line': line}

  # Else, if this 'Name' is not new and the TSS is less, keep this new line
  elif tss < abc[name]['tss']:
    abc[name]['line'] = line
```

Comment: I was going to go with something like this too (i.e. avoid the `if abc[name] < ...` that I use, but as the OP wants to keep the whole line I thought it better to not just use the `min` function (also it's min, not max that the OP asked for).

Comment: Edited to reflect correct specs from OP (sorry, was in a rush before)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IronSpread](http://www.ironspread.com/) which gives you a python console and a way to script actions like this in python. It also supports UDFs that you can use as normal excel functions, which is nice.

Comment: Assuming the OP is on windows and has excel... or IronSpread is supported by `wine` (and the OP has excel) - they could have been given excel files to work with without having excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pyvot, available from the Python Tools for Visual Studio team. It provides a comprehensive API for working with Excel spreadsheets from CPython.

You can get the code from PyPi: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyvot
And you can get documentation from the Pytools site: http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pyvot